# How To Upgrade from MySQL 5.1.72 to 5.5.45 in 1and1 vps

Tags: mysql, wordpress, vps, mysql-error-1064

I have bought VPS from 1and1.com and changed name server of my domain (previously it was on godaddy ) . But i noticed in godaddy i was using MySQL 5.5.45 and here on 1and1 mysql version is 5.1.72

Due to this when i have run my database script on 1and1 with 5.1.72 MySQL version it is giving error

**Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'**

My Database is wordpress database - i am having error at below code as this code contains 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=174 ;
```

Comment: You need MySQL 5.5.3 or higher to support the utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation.

Comment: in addition, if you have not plans to store any chinese characters and/or emoticons in your database, you can change charset and collation to pure utf8.

Comment: @mitkosoft thanks i am going to try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before.
I have changed "utf8mb4" to "utf8" in the script file.
And "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" to "utf8_general_ci".
So, script was executed successfully.
Hope, help this to you.

Comment: I am going to try the solution

Comment: This must not to be done (and suggest) unconditionally, there is a reason to exists `utf8mb4`. Lot of non-standard characters are not supported by regular utf8 as chinese for example.